# Why is package "com.android.bluetooth" querying our MediaBrowserService on Samsung devices?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-mobile, android-auto

Our app contains a `MediaBrowserService` and uses a whitelist to restrict who can can query the service. It is typically used to permit Android Auto and Android Wear to query our app for audio content.  As far as I know, this is still a recommended approach.  For example, as shown in this Google sample app: [MediaBrowserService sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/xml/allowed_media_browser_callers.xml)

Our app reports the package names that try to query our `MediaBrowserService` but are NOT on the whitelist.   We fairly regularly receive reports that "com.android.bluetooth" tried to call our service and was denied.

I'm perplexed by these reports. We've never seen such calls from this package on our own test devices. My previous attempts to ask the user if they have a Bluetooth device that might be displaying audio information has been met with confusion...so it seems perhaps Android itself is making these calls?

Has anyone else encountered this? This whitelist approach requires validating specific signing certificates.  Does com.android.bluetooth have a consistent signing certificate that can be used to add this package to the whitelist?

**UPDATE 1:**

Looking at the reports we have received from users, this appears to be exclusively a Samsung Android 6.0.1 phenomenon. The first report of it showed up on 3/13/2016 and there has been a steady trickle all summer.

Here's a partial list of the models that have reported this issue. All of them have had Android 6.0.1.  Could this be related to their Tizen-based Galaxy Gear watches?

- Galaxy Note 4 (SM-N910R4)
- Galaxy Note 4 (SAMSUNG-SM-N910A)
- Galaxy Note 5 (SM-N920V)
- Galaxy S5 (SM-G900V)
- Galaxy S5 Active (SAMSUNG-SM-G870A)
- Galaxy S6 (SM-G920R7)
- Galaxy S6 (SAMSUNG-SM-G890A)
- Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935V)
- Galaxy S7 Edge (SAMSUNG-SM-G935A)
- Galaxy J7    (SM-J700T1)

**UPDATE 2:**

I have finally reproduced the situation on a Galaxy S6 Edge with 6.0.1.  Bluetooth on the device simply has to be turned on.  If turned on, with nothing even paired or connected, when I start playing audio in our app "com.android.bluetooth" (UID 1002) calls `onGetRoot` and `onLoadChildren` on our `MediaBrowserService`.  WHY!?  If I allow it, nothing visible changes on the device.  I thought I might see some Samsung widget presenting the media info from our app...but I don't.

Comment: Any progress with this? Any new things?

Comment: No.  We used to log all non-white-listed callers of our MediaBrowserService but these Samsung devices were spamming it so much that we simply stopped logging this information.    So I "fixed" it by no longer looking for it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I suppose it might be related to their Tizen-based watches but, if so, it seems odd to repeatedly call the MediaBrowerService when a watch isn't connected.  I don't have access to a Gear watch to test this theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon an answer, of sorts.  For reasons only someone at Samsung probably knows, the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat.onGetRoot` call by package "com.android.bluetooth" relates to `MediaSessionCompat.setMediaButtonReceiver`.

If you are using `MediaSessionCompat` in a manner explained by the documentation for [Using media buttons to restart an inactive media session](http://Using%20media%20buttons%20to%20restart%20an%20inactive%20media%20session), these Samsung devices are querying `MediaBrowserServiceCompat.onGetRoot` with the com.android.blueooth package before media button events are sent to the `BroadcastReceiver` configured by `MediaSessionCompat.setMediaButtonReceiver` when Android attempts to revive the last active MediaSession.

If the call to `onGetRoot` returns null because you haven't whitelisted the com.android.bluetooth package, your BroadcastReceiver will NOT receive media button events and the inactive media session won't be revived. You can either fully whitelist the package and return your normal `BrowserRoot` of real data or return an empty `BrowserRoot`. For example, `new MediaBrowserServiceCompat.BrowserRoot("myroot", null)`.  Samsung doesn't appear to actually use the root data or make subsequent calls to `MediaBrowserServive.onLoadChildren` so it doesn't seem to matter what you return in response to onGetRoot calls made by com.android.bluetooth, it just can't be `null`.

Again, this situation seems to be unique to Samsung's 6.0.1 Android builds. I have not encountered any other devices or any other Samsung Android builds that perform this curious call by com.android.bluetooth.

Comment: this is really silly, I stumbled upon the same problem on Samsung J5

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, this is related to new features which Android 5.0 offers for users and app developers which includes most notable new [Android 5.0 APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html).

As mentioned in [Media browsing](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#MediaBrowsing),

> Android 5.0 introduces the ability for apps to browse the media content library of another app, through the new [android.media.browse API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/browse/package-summary.html).

For this recent [**Android 5.0 Behavior Changes**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#updates), you should carefully assess possible impacts on your app for the given points to consider such as [Custom Permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#custom_permissions). Aside from that, it is also recommended that you examine your app immediately, make any adjustments needed, and publish the updated version as soon as possible to your users.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're describing the MediaBrowserService?  Yes, I understand the basic functions of it.  After all, it's been in our app for a year or two by now. The question is, why is the com.android.bluetooth package specifically calling in to the MediaBrowserService.  And only on Samsung devices?  This is not normal behavior.

I'm looking for an explanation of why this package in particular is calling the service. I would like to figure out steps to reproduce it so we can either add the proper certificate to the whitelist or submit it to Samsung as a possible bug.